# Frequently Modified Files in Clearcase

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am very new to Clearcase and one of the task that I have got on my hand is to find frequently modified  files in ClearCase, Suppose we have an integration stream and there are numerous files in our stream, need to know of certain files which are modified frequently like a certain file is modified 5 times in last two months.

I have access to ClearCase commands as well as GUI

Is there a way we can have solution to this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do, following [find examples](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/additional-examples-cleartool-find-command), a search between two dates:

```
cleartool find . -version "{created_since(date1) &&
                           !created_since(date2) &&
                           brtype(myIntStream)" -exec "cleartool descr -fmt "%En"\
|sort| uniq -c | sort -n
```

(This is the Windows syntax, which means you need [GoW (Gnu On Windows)](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) installed for the `v`  and `uniq` commands.

As [Brian Cowan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4223401/brian-cowan) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62637117/frequently-modified-files-in-clearcase/62637836#comment110787758_62637836), the command would be:

```
cleartool find -all -version "{created_since(date1) &&
                           !created_since(date2) &&
                           brtype(myIntStream)" -exec "cleartool desc -fmt \"%En\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN\"" \
|sort| uniq -c | sort -n
```

On Unix:

```
cleartool find -all -version "{created_since(date1) &&
                           !created_since(date2) &&
                           brtype(myIntStream)" -exec  'cleartool desc -fmt "%En\n" "$CLEARCASE_XPN"' \
|sort| uniq -c | sort -n
```

> `-all` instead of the current directory format, to avoid issues if the command isn't run at the VOB root.

> If you don't care about the interval, but only want the last 2 months, drop the `!created_since` line.
> Alternatively, use "`today`" as the second date, though that would everything modified since midnight your local on the day you run the command.

Comment: This actually needs to be -exec, and the exec string should be "cleartool desc -fmt \"%En\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN\"" you need the escaping to keep cleartool on WIndows from getting upset. On UNix, the exec would be 'cleartool desc -fmt "%En\n" "$CLEARCASE_XPN"' Also, you may want to use -all instead of the current directory format to avoid issues if the command isn't run @ the VOB root.

Comment: Note 2: If you don't care about the interval, but only want the last 2 months, drop the !created_since line. Alternatively, use "today" as the second date, though that would everything modified since midnight your local on the day you run the command.

Comment: Thanks Both @VonC and Brian Cowan for both of your valuable inputs, I am running cleartool find . -version "{created_since(20-jun-18) && !created_since(20-jun-20) }" -print -exec "cleartool desc -fmt \"%En\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN\""  from inside one of my view and getting below error  cleartool: Error: Unable to access "%CLEARCASE_XPN": No such file or directory    , when I run cleartool find . -version "{created_since(20-jun-18) && !created_since(20-jun-20) }" -print   I get the output with files

Comment: @bhardwajme On which OS are you on for your ClearCase client? Windows? And which version (of Windows, and of ClearCase)?

Comment: @bhardwajme Since I have edited the answer, consider the second part: the one with `-exec "cleartool descr"`: there is no `-print -exec`: it is either `-print`, or `-exec`.

Comment: @VonC Breaking my reply in two comments -- When I use the branch option I do not get any output "cleartool find -all -version "{created_since(20-jun-18) && !created_since(20-jun-20) && brtype(stream:stream_name@\Vobname)}" -exec "cleartool desc -fmt \"%En\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN\"" |sort " when I run this command
but running command without branch option "cleartool find -all -version "{created_since(20-jun-18) && !created_since(20-jun-20) }" -exec "cleartool desc -fmt \"%En\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN\"" |sort" get error "cleartool: Error: Unable to access "%CLEARCASE_XPN": No such file or directory."

Comment: Above commands I am running inside a view when I run with branch option the first command in my above comment at any random path(not inside a view ) it gives me error "cleartool: Error: Not an object in a vob: ".".
cleartool: Warning: Skipping "."."
I am running them on Windows CC Client,Windows 10 and ClearCase version 9.0.0.00

Comment: @bhardwajme Snapshot or dynamic views?

Comment: @VonC Currently using dynamic View